# Change Shape of Array in Numpy

Tags: numpy

I have an array with shape `(144,)`.

I have a vector of data with shape `(2,144)`. For example, two readings from two sensors. Every readings has `144` values.

I would like to stick a time slot to each sensor reading, in order to have a matrix of `(2,144,2)`: the first axis is the number of sensors; the second the number of readings, and the third the number of entries of each record, in this case 2 because I sticked the time axis.

I first tried to reshape the time axis vector to match the right shape, with:

```
np.broadcast_to(time_axis,(144,2))
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with remapped shapes [original->remapped]: (144,) and requested shape (144,2)
```

[image]

I tried also with:

```
numOfVec = 2
num = 144
time_axis =  np.broadcast_to(time_axis,(numOfVec,num)).T            
# Add time axis
out = np.vstack((time_axis,synthetic.T))
```

**UPDATE**

I tried the hint given in a comment:

```
time_axis = self.datetime_range(10)
time_axis = np.reshape(time_axis,(1,num))
time_axis = np.repeat(time_axis,numOfVec,axis=0)
# Add time axis
out = np.stack((time_axis,synthetic))
```

It works but since I have to jsonify the data, the result is not correct:

```
"data": [
        [
            [
                "00:00:00",
                "00:10:00",
                "00:20:00",
                "00:30:00",
              ...
             ]
         ]
```

I would like to obtain something like this:

```
"data": [
        [
            [
                "00:00:00",
                "19.2"
            ],
            [    
                "00:10:00",
                "29.1"
            ]
        ]
        ]
```

Comment: "and the third the number of entries of each record, in this case 2 because I sticked the time axis": can you elaborate, perhaps with an example?

Comment: Do you have a (2,144) shaped array of those "time axis" values?

Comment: added a picture. it should be clearer now.

Comment: You can `reshape` a (144,) to (1,144).  Then use `repeat` to make it (2,144).  Finally `stack` the 2 on a new last axis.

Comment: it works but now I have a problem with jsonify...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution

```
# Convert to 2D array
time_axis = np.reshape(time_axis,(num,1))
# Add third dimensions
time_axis = np.expand_dims(time_axis, axis=0)
# Repeat time axis on third dimension
time_axis = np.repeat(time_axis,numOfVec,axis=0)
# Add time axis to sensor readings by sticking along the second dimension (axis = 2)
out = np.concatenate((time_axis,synthetic),axis=2)
```